# Shopify If multiple tags are present - do something

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to simply show a div if a set of tags are present. I have it working with 1 tag by using...

```
{% if collection.all_tags contains 'TAG1' %}
    DO SOMETHING
{% endif %}
```

...but I want to check if multiple tags are present like...

```
{% if collection.all_tags contains 'TAG1 or TAG2 or TAG3' %}
    DO SOMETHING
{% endif %}
```

I can't find any solution to this but it seems fairly simple, any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{% if collection.all_tags contains 'tag1' or collection.all_tags contains 'tag2' %}
    DO SOMETHING
{% endif %}
```

[See the list of Liquid operators here](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/operators).